# The controller for path '/apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png' was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting some error messages in my web log file.

1. The controller for path '/apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png' was not found or does not implement IController. Path::/apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png
2. The controller for path '/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png' was not found or does not implement IController. Path::/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png
3. Error:The controller for path '/apple-touch-icon.png' was not found or does not implement IController. Path::/apple-touch-icon.png

I have checked in all pages that I don't use these icons in my web application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are files for Apple iOS devices. Probably a user has added your website on their home screen. iOS then tries to find those images in order to create a nice icon for you. You can read more about that in the [Safari documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html).

Like this one, which is actually a web app, but shows like a native app:

> [image: iOS screen with web app]

What you should do is create and add those images files. This will improve your user experience.

Comment: I have make (120px x 120px) 3 icons 1. apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png, 2. apple-touch-icon-120x120.png, 3. apple-touch-icon.png of my website logo and upload on root. Is it ok.

Comment: Yes. It is best to add the ignore rule from the other post too.

Answer (score 7):

Some IOS device is trying to get this image from your site. ASP.MVC engine tries to fetch a controller called "/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" and throws an exception. You can create a route that ignores this call and avoid throwing this exception:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*apple}", new { apple = @"(.*/)?apple-touch-icon.*\.png(/.*)?" });
```

You should also create an image for IOS and improve UX on IOS devices as Patrick answered.